# make non registered users see events in joomsocial

Tags: joomla

I am using jomsocial on my project and I want to show the events on jomsocial to the public also. That means non registered users can also see events. Is that possible? Any one please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find "Events" in the jomsocial menu, and set its access level to public (should be registered now). Also make sure you enable events in the jomsocial configuration